# Is this the correct way to check in PHP that a checkbox is checked?

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

I have this code to check that my ToS checkbox is checked:

```
if (!isset($_POST['tosagree'])) {//if the user did not agree to ToS
    $errors[] = '<span>Please agree to the Terms of Service.<span>';
}
```

For some reason it is allowing me to register even with that code there. The weird thing is that if any other field is not field and that field is not checked it will print the error, but if that is the only problem it allows the user to register.

Update: seems like its a problem with something weird in my code. If you feel like looking through 217 lines of code here is all the code: http://pastebin.com/YkERYpeF

Comment: Your solution should work - I use the same approach, and its works lika a charme…
`if(isset($_POST['register_sent']))
{
 if(!isset($_POST['check_agb_checkbox']))
 {
  $error[] = $l->error('accept_standard_form_contract');
 }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether `!isset($_POST['tosagree'])` will be enough depends on the browser.

To be safe, always set the `value` attribute of the checkbox. Then, you simply check if that value is present:

```
<input type='checkbox' value='agreed'/>
```

Then do this:

```
if (!isset($_POST['tosagree']) || $_POST['tosagree'] != "agreed" ) {
    $errors[] = '<span>Please agree to the Terms of Service.<span>';
}
```

Also, when the `value` attribute is not explicitly specified, browsers will usually set `value` to `On` when it is checked.

## Edit

Ok, I know what's happening. In your PHP code, you have this block:

```
if (!isset($_POST['tosagree']) || $_POST['tosagree'] != "agreed") {//if the user did not agree to ToS
    $errors[] = '<span>Please agree to the Terms of Service.<span>';
}
```

Then later you have this line:

```
if ($un && $e && $p && $ic) { //if there are no errors
```

The problem is that you don't have a flag for when the TOS checkbox isn't checked. The error can't be printed because in the `if` statement you have a call to `exit()`.

Comment: hmm... didn't work :( I just posted all the code because it seems to be something with the other code if you want to wade through that it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try echoing out the value of $_POST["tosagree"]. What is it when you check it and when you don't?

Comment: @SimpleCoder When checked it prints the value and when unchecked it has a error: "Undefined index: tosagree"

Comment: @SimpleCoder Also it only prints the error when another field is not correct otherwise it doesn't echo it.

Comment: Hmm... I probably should have guessed that from your name :).

Comment: @SimpleCoder yeah, it does the same thing firefox too though so its not webkit related

Comment: @SimpleCoder if you want to try it live go to blankit.co.cc/register/ and use the Alpha Code of `testcode`. (there's nothing other than a registration page pretty much and I will delete any signups currently)

Comment: To be honest with you, I see nothing wrong with your code. I'm not sure why it's not working. Sorry,

Comment: and you can sign up as many times as you want because I just added 100 invites to that code.

Comment: I'll try out your form though

Comment: ahh... thanks so much. Those little things can really slip by without you knowing it.

Comment: @chromedude: You're welcome! Yeah, I've forgotten stuff like that too. For future reference, Chrome's Developer Tools are very helpful. When I submitted the registration, I could see the POST data as it was submitted. I saw that the `tosagree` field wasn't in the request, so I assumed it was an error with the PHP code. In Firefox you can use Firebug.

Comment: hmm... ok didn't think of that option... thanks. I usually use that but hadn't thought of the POST part.